# Netbeans Java .append repeats output four times

Tags: java, string, loops, netbeans, append

why does it appear "my name is" 4 times when I type your name into the input text field

> public void compareQuestion(){
>
> String fileName = directory + "memoryBank.txt";

```
      String line = null;

    try {

        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split(" - ");
            String subject = parts[0];
            String question = parts[1];
            String answer = parts[2];
            //if(input.equals(question) && !subject.equals(currentSubject)){ currentSubject = subject; }
           // if(input.equals(question) && subject.equals(currentSubject)){ Output.append(answer); }
            if(input.contains("what is your name")) { 
                Output.append("my name is"+ newline);
            }
        }   

        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I have added a SSCCE ...

Comment: A Short, Self Contained, Compilable, Example (SSCCE) can be compiled and run, you have provided code _snippets_ which don't give a full picture of what the issue might be

Comment: The code I have provided is all you need to see a recreate the problem.

Comment: @String.userName: Nope, I can't recreate the problem with the code you posted (and I have a feeling it's not only me).

Comment: Put the first code below "public static void main ect.." the second code above it put drag a text area and field ont the design and run. why what happens when you do it?

Comment: You are registering the action listener more the once, but you haven't provided enough code for use to point where you are doing this

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have added more code can you explain further

Comment: It appears to be revolving around `newLine`, did you mean to say `line`? Also, it could be doing this because it never goes to the next line with a `\n` argument, unless of course the `newLine` variable is in fact equal to `\n`

Comment: @string.username What is input and how is its value defined?

Comment: @Legend yes newline is equal to \n

Comment: @MadProgrammer input is a string which is taken from a text line in which the user can input text (JTextField).

Answer (score 1):

Without a running example, I believe your probelm is here...

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = line.split(" - ");
    String subject = parts[0];
    String question = parts[1];
    String answer = parts[2];
    //if(input.equals(question) && !subject.equals(currentSubject)){ currentSubject = subject; }
    // if(input.equals(question) && subject.equals(currentSubject)){ Output.append(answer); }
    if(input.contains("what is your name")) { 
        Output.append("my name is"+ newline);
    }
}
```

Baically, on each run of the loop, if the `JTextField` `input` contains the text `what is your name`, it will append the `String` `"my name is"+ newline` to the textfield.  If you have 4 questions in the file, it will be append 4 times, if you have 100 questions, it will be appended 100 times.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, however I believe another problem is the .contains, if I change it to .equals it works fine but I haven't used .contains before and am not sure quit how it works but it seems more useful than equals.

Comment: `contains` allows you to do a kind of wild card selection (the wildcard element is automatic).  If any part of the `String` matches the input, then it will return true, other wise it returns false.  `equals` requires that the whole `String` match the input

Answer (score 0):

After playing around for a couple of hours I managed to fix it with a little help from MadProgrammer.
fixed code:

I couldn't get block quote to work so here is an image:

[image]